# Google Cloud SQL setup & connecting to App Maker

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I'm trying to get a Cloud SQL database connected to Google App Maker. I've followed the step by step instructions found here: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql, apparently successfully (no error messages in setup.)

But, still getting the error message that it isn't set up properly, and the instance name is incorrect. :/

What. in the world.

Also, when I go back into App Maker and click on settings, I do not get a "database" option to select.

How do I proceed??

Comment: If you follow all the steps properly, allow some time. Sometimes it takes up to 4 hours for the settings to propagate. In the weird scenarios, up to 24.

Comment: Thanks, but it's been 2+ days already. :/  I've even requested setup (???), with no change.

Comment: Unfortunately your description is too vague to help you. Instead of going back and forth with several questions, I suggest you to reach out to G Suite Support and ask for the API team. They should be able to help you get setup.

Comment: I shared the instructions I followed and gave the exact error message I keep getting. How is that vague?

Comment: Please don't take it personal. But in order to help you, I would ask you to share some screen shots about your SQL configuration, your admin console configuration, the project on GCP, also if the project is part of the organization. Those are only the first questions, depending on the answers there are more things to check. G Suite Support is better for this since there might be sensitive information which is not safe to provide via this channel.  https://gsuite.google.com/support/

Comment: That is more helpful information; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must firs setup CloudSql instance in G-suite admin https://support.google.com/a/answer/7550053?hl=en